# Suggestions on improving my proof of a basic equivalence class property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

I am currently brushing up on some *very* basic set theory, as I've been away from proof writing and such for a few years.  The statement I wrote a proof for is:

> If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$ then
> $[x]\neq[y]\iff[x]\cap[y]=\emptyset$.

For context, I wrote this statement myself (another skillset I am rebuilding) and recognize that it comes off as a bit awkward (although I believe it is a true statement). In any case, here is the proof I wrote.  I am looking for general advice regarding clarity and conciseness, as well as any suggestions on what I may add or remove to make this proof stronger.  Of course, if there are any errors please point those out!

> Proof.
>
> ($\Rightarrow$)  Let $X$ be a set with equivalence relation $\sim$.
> For $x,y\in X$ assume that $$[x]\neq[y].$$  Suppose towards a
> contradiction that $[x]\cap[y]\neq\emptyset$.  If this intersection is
> nonempty, then there is some $z$ such that $z\in[x]$ and $z\in[y]$. By
> definition of equivalence class, $z\in[x]$ implies that $z\sim x$ and,
> similarly, $z\in[y]$ implies that $z\sim y$.  Since $\sim$ is
> transitive, this means that $x\sim y$.  Therefore $x\sim a$ for all
> $a\in[y]$ and $y\sim b$ for all $b\in[x]$.  Thus $[x]=[y]$, a
> contradiction.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$)  Suppose that $[x]\cap[y]=\emptyset$.  Assume towards a
> contradiction that $[x]=[y]$.
>
> If $z\in[x]$ then $z\in[y]$ by definition of set equality.  Thus
> $z\in[x]\cap[y]$, a contradiction.
> $\blacksquare$

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall this is a good solution. As mentioned in the other answer, some more details on how $z\sim x$ and $z\sim y$ implies $x\sim y$, in particular through symmetry and transitivity, would be a good idea. Go through it one step at a time, making note of exactly which property you're using where. And also how this implies that $x\sim a$ for all $a\in [y]$ and $y\sim b$ for all $b\in [x]$.

As a matter of aesthetics, I personally don't like to use contradiction where it is unnecessary. In your first part, you only really use $[x]\cap [y]\neq\emptyset$, and conclude that $[x]=[y]$. No need for contradiction there, no need to assume $[x]\neq [y]$. What you have is just a pure proof by contraposition. Similarly for the second part you just need to assume the two classes are equal, and you can show that the intersection is non-empty (as it clearly contains, at the very least, $x$). No need to also assume that the intersection is empty.

Which is to say, you have actually proven $$[x]=[y]\iff [x]\cap [y]\neq\emptyset$$by direct proof.

Comment: So, as a follow up question to this answer, does proving $[x]=[y]\iff [x]\cap [y]\neq\emptyset$ directly allow us to conclude (without additional proof) that $[x]\neq[y]\iff[x]\cap[y]=\emptyset$?

Comment: @ThyArtisMath Yes. This is a basic logic property. That's part of what $\iff$ means.

Answer (score 2):

**This looks good.** I have one (very minor) suggestion if you're trying to be include every detail. Your answer already deserves full marks IMO.

In the first part, you have $z \sim x$ and $z \sim y$, and you wish to conclude that $x \sim y$. In addition to the transitive property, this also requires the symmetric property to first deduce that $x \sim z$. This last relation can be combined transitively with the fact that $z \sim y$ to reach your conclusion that $x \sim y$.